# Dichotomous variable based on conditionals in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe similar to this one:

```
date <- as.Date(c('2010-11-1','2010-11-2','2010-11-3','2010-11-4','2010-11-5','2010-11-6','2010-11-7','2010-11-8','2010-11-9','2010-11-10'))
precipitation <- c(0, 11, 12,3,0,0,0,7,9,10)
snowheight <- c(5,7,56,32, 11, 24, 70,8, 13, 11)
temperature <- c(-5, -2, 0, 0.4, -1, 5,6,4, 9, 10)
df <- data.frame(date, precipitation, snowheight, temperature)
```

I am trying to create a dichotomous variable with (0 and 1) for each datasample based on the following conditions:

- if snowheight > 10 we continue with the conditions below. Else assign NA to the dichotomous variable.
- if precipitation =< 0 we assign 0
- if precipitation > 0 and temperature > 0 we assign 1.
- if precipitation > 0 and temperature < 0 we assign 0.

I figured out that it is easy to use ifelse with nested conditions, however, this will not work due to the partially overlapping conditions. The next thing that comes to my mind is to use for-loop and check for every row. This is what I figured out:

```
for (i in df){
  if (snowheight > 10 && rain > 0){
    if (temperature > 0){
      df$dicht <- 1
    } else {
      df$dicht <- 0
    }
  } else {
    df$dicht <- NA
  }
}
```

When I run the code like this I get a variable "dicht" filled entirely with "NA". I think see what type of mistake that is but I am not sure how to fix it. It seems that written this way the whole "dicht" variable gets assigned with the value instead of the indexed row. I tried like this:

```
for (i in df){
  if (snowheight > 10 && rain > 0){
    if (temperature > 0){
      df$dicht [i] <- 1
    } else {
      df$dicht [i] <- 0
    }
  } else {
    df$dicht [i] <- NA
  }
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "dicht", value = c(NA, NA, NA, NA,  :
> replacement has 14923 rows, data has 10

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use vectorized operations

```
df <- transform(df, dicht = +(snowheight > 10 & 
        precipitation > 0 & temperature > 0))
df$dicht[df$snowheight <=10] <- NA
```

---

The loop in OP's code should be run by row index and not by 'df'

```
df$dicht <- NA
for (i in seq_len(nrow(df))){
  if (df$snowheight[i] > 10 && df$precipitation[i] > 0){
    if (df$temperature[i] > 0){
      df$dicht [i] <- 1
    } else {
      df$dicht [i] <- 0
    }
  } else {
    df$dicht [i] <- NA
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Both solutions: your and the upgrade of mine work. I have to read more into the "transform" function to fully comprehend how it works as I am not exactly sure so far. That is base R right? Thanks

Comment: @ZorinIvanov both are `base R`

Comment: Thanks. How should I adapt the code if some of the condition variables occasionally contain missing values (NA)?

Comment: @ZorinIvanov in that case, you can add a condition with `!is.na(df$snoweight[i]) &&` so that it if the elements are NA, it returns FALSE instead of NA

Comment: Actually, I would prefer to receive a NA in the dichtomous variable if some of the condition variables contain NA, so that it gets excluded from the statistics, just like if snowheight is below 10.

Comment: @ZorinIvanov Then you may need the is.na at the top `if(is.na(df$snoweight[i]) NA_integer else if`

Comment: Also, any computation with `NA` returns NA, thus you may not have the issue in the current code

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a good fit for a solution with `dplyr::case_when()`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(dicht = case_when(snowheight <=10 ~ NA_real_,
                                precipitation <= 0 ~ 0,
                                precipitation > 0 & temperature > 0 ~ 1,
                                precipitation > 0 & temperature <= 0 ~ 0))
```

Comment: When I try your code I get the following Error: "Problem with `mutate()` input `dicht`.
x must be a logical vector, not a double vector.
i Input `dicht` is `case_when(...)`."